# Octave - error: 'fwt' undefined after installing the required package

Tags: octave

I have installed the `ltfat` package as referenced, [here](https://octave.sourceforge.io/ltfat/function/fwt.html), as I want to use the `fwt` function.

I downloaded the package from, [here](https://octave.sourceforge.io/ltfat/index.html), and then ran the following command in the Octave command-line window:

```
pkg install -forge ltfat
```

I'm however having the following error:

```
error: 'fwt' undefined
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the package before using its functions. i.e.

```
pkg load ltfat
```

This is mentioned in the documentation of both [Octave](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Using-Packages.html) and [ltfat package](https://github.com/ltfat/ltfat/releases/tag/2.4.0).

Comment: Great! Thanks so much.